# C# nuget package dependency consolidation fails when running app as azure webjob

Tags: c#, azure, dependencies, nuget

The exception when running as the console application as Azure webjob:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Locally this works and runs.

Referencing:

- Azure.Identity version 1.3.0 which has a dependency to Azure.Core version >= 1.6.0
- Azure.Security.KeyVaults.Secrets version 4.1.0 which has a dependency to Azure.Core version >= 1.0.2

So of course based on these nuspec specifications it should resolve to Azure.Core 1.6.0. Which it locally does and runs without a problem.

Yet when I deploy this using VS publish profile to our cloud as Azure Webjobs and run the application I get the exception mentioned above. (of course the file version deployed is the same as local, version 1.6.0)

I know I can fix this with an assemblybinding. Stating that version 0.0.0.0 to 1.6.0.0 should resolve to version 1.6.0.0.

But I find this very frustrating because it imposes manual labor and keeps us from updating packages whenever a newer version arrives because then we also have to remind ourselves to update the assemblybindings.

I feel like there is a better solution, or we are doing something wrong. But I simply do not know where to begin searching for a solution. I hope to get some insights from you guys!

PS:

This phenomenon is driving me nuts because we face similar issues when using packages:

- Unity
- Unity.Interception

Because they both depend on Unity.Container. Forcing us to either use assemblybinding to resolve this issue, or only use versions which depend on the same packages

Comment: Okay - so whats you question?

Comment: you could try to manually delete the bin and obj folder as well as the package.config files. Then clear the nuget cache. (ofcourse all from the targeted machine)

After that redeploy via the publish profile.

Comment: @sommmen my question would be, is there something I am doing wrong that is causing this exception. Or is the only solution to use the assemblybinding

Comment: @Proliges I do a clear of the folder where I deploy to before I publish. And I don't think the targeted machine has cached nuget packages... isn't that resolved locally into .dll files into the /bin/ folder. And then published?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer here, but I know a possible way to get more infomation.  If you deploy and run fuslogvw.exe as a background task on the webjob, that should give you log info about what is happening to the binding evaulations at runtime, which may help answer your question.  Remember to also copy flogvwrc.dll .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg I do think it has something to do with cached files. Locally your project builds and runs, but on the target machine you run into assembly issues. That is a result from either cached code or redundant code from your target machine refering to these files. 

You could just remove the entire project from your target machine to make sure no redundant code is left behind. I have had this issue before on our IIS server where i published to. That solved the issue for me at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following steps because the approach you are taking is correct:

- Uninstall both `Azure.Identity` and `Azure.Security.KeyVaults.Secrets` nuget packages.
- Remove all the associated Assembly Bindings.
- Delete `bin` and `obj` folders in your project folder.
- Install `Azure.Core version >= 1.6.0` and rebuild the solution.
- Deploy the solution.

These should work ideally. I think that there are some stale dependencies which are getting deployed. You can also try deploying through pipelines, if not already doing.